# Very slow clipboard copy from Scripting window

Tags: windows-7, powershell, copy-paste, powershell-ise

I have an issue in PowerShell ISE (Windows 7) where it takes around 2-3 seconds after copying some text from the scripting area before it actually saves into the clipboard. During this time the ISE window is unresponsive.

I don't experience this on any other machine, only my main computer at work, and I can't seem to find anything else on the internet about it.

My PC has done this for as long as I can remember, so still experiencing the issue after many a PC and ISE restart.

I also noticed the delay is present no matter how I copy the text:

`Ctrl + C`

`Right-Click + 'Copy'`

`$ "test text" | clip`

Does anyone know what causes this issue, and how I can resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried launching the ISE without a profile? `powershell_ise.exe -NoProfile`

Comment: @root Thanks for your comment - just tried that and there is still about a 2 second delay when copying

Comment: Are other copy to clipboard commands slow as well? Have you tried restarting PowerShellI ISE? Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: @DavidPostill Copy and Paste both work normally in other applications - it is only in ISE that I sae this issue. It happens no matter which way I copy the text (I tried 3 different methods listed in the question)

Comment: i'd first try a `sfc /scannow` which almost never helps but still is a good starting point. if that doesn't cure the issue, have you considered updating your PowerShell to a new version?

Comment: @SimonS I think the `sfc /scannow` actually did it!

Comment: @Bassie ok very nice! i'll expand it to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sfc /scannow` to scan and repair missing or corrupted system files.

To view the log of the sfc execution, use:

```
findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"
```

More Information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833